# How to retrieve table datas using json django

Tags: python, ajax, django, json

Am learning ajax with json. From template I can bring the datas to views using ajax and can store the given values in table. I want to retrieve the datas from table using json.

views.py

```
def disptable(request):
    if 'name' and 'age' in request.GET:
        n=request.GET['name']
        a=request.GET['age']
        tablestoreajax(name=n,age=a).save()
    d="wowwwww"
    return render(request,"tablestore.html",json.dumps(d))
```

models.py

```
class tablestoreajax(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

template file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sub').click(function(){
        var na=$('#id1').val()
        var ag=$('#id2').val()
         var dataString = {name:na,age:ag};
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        data:dataString,
      datatype:'json',
        url:'/disptable/',
        success:function(data) {
        alert(data.a);
      }
  });
    });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
name<input type="text" id="id1" name="name1">
age<input type="text" id="id2" name="age1">
<input type ="submit" id="sub" value="save">
</body>
</html>
```

In my views I used json.dumps()- but I read that dumps() is used for dictionaries. What to use to bring the details to templates.

Answer (score 0):

> In my views I used json.dumps()- but I read that dumps() is used for dictionaries. What to use to bring the details to templates.

You need to actually pass the variable (through a dictionary) from the view.py to the template.

```
#view.py
def disptable(request):
    ..
    ..
    d="wowwwww"
    return render(request,"tablestore.html",{"jsonVal":json.dumps(d)})
```

And in the template, use it where you want. For example to pass the JSON value above to a javascript variable, use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonValFromServer = {{ jsonVal }};
</script>
```

Upon page load (in your browser), view the HTML source to verify the above.

<sup>PS: Its been a bit long since I worked on django, I might be wrong above, but you get the idea of how its supposed to be done.</sup>